# Is there a different way (without spoon) to receive Holy Communion in the Orthodox Church?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, communion, oriental-orthodox

Orthodox Churches (including Greek Catholics) distribute Holy Communion with a single spoon used without cleaning for the whole community. I find this practice unhygienic. Are there different ways that I can receive Communion in Orthodox Churches and how can I ask to introduce them in my parish? E.g. Roman Catholics can receive Holy Communion in their hands or on their tounges, the chalice is cleaned after use and so on.

Comment: I would suggest that one with these concerns could maybe approach the Holy Eucharist with a different mindset. If one is truly convinced and believes that this is the Holy Blood of Christ, concerns over how hygenic the spoon that administers the Holy Blood will become of less concern. Truly the Blood of Christ can heal of any infirmity or sickness.

Answer (score 2):

Well, technically, yes. If you are very sick and can't stand from your bed, you can invite a priest to give you Communion personally, so you'll be the only person to Commune this day. However, lying to the priest to receive Communion is pretty bad idea.

So, as **Abbanoob** said in the comments, you'd better rethink your concerns about this, maybe talking to the priest himself.